# Finding arithmetic mean, with hidden ratios, HOW?

Tags: education

I have twelve items each with with their own percentage of 100%.
I'll label them..

English(A):67 -MATH(B):60.5 -Biology(B):67.5 -Chemistry(C):80 -Physics(E):67 ARABIC(F):63 -Economics(G):78.5 -History(H):78 -Computer(I):94.5 -French(J):95 -Geography(k):83.5 -Social Studies(L):95.5

These are grades from my sister's transcript Totaling a GPD of : 73.95
All I know is the first six subjects are the most important so they'll have a higher ratio, and the rest six are least important, or it could 3 less important and later 3 lesser.
Anyway the are properly arranged in priority, although the first six aren't because they warrant the same priority.

So what I'm trying to figure out is how does the some of all of them average to 73.95%
I've been asking the school but they've been evading me and refused further contact, there are no laws against knowing the ratio I checked with Abu Dhabi's 
ministry of education but still the school refuses to answer, So I'm resorting to the community for help, and I hope I find it.
Thank you in advance, and I shall thank you later friend !

Comment: If there are hidden ratios, you need more report cars to find them. You'd need at least $11$ report cards to come up with a strict, mathematical solution (there are $12$ hidden variables, but you already know that they sum up to $1$).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first six subjects all have the same percentage $x$ and the other six all the same percentage $y=1/6-x$, then you get $x\simeq11.3\%$ and $y\simeq5.4\%$.

Of course this changes if – as you say – there is third lower percentage for the last three subjects, which should be $z=1/3-2x-y$. 
In that case you get no definite answer, but rather a range corresponding to $x=12.16\%-0.16y$.